# accessing returned promise object array values

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm trying to access the length of an array returned from the promise object. However, I'm not getting any luck for it to work as it returns undefined when i check the array itself, and i try to access the specific element its says cannot read property

from the chrome console

```
f {$promise: Object, $resolved: false, $get: function, $save: function, $query: function…}
$promise: Object
$resolved: true
address: "1600 amphitheatre way , Mountain View, CA 94043"
address_1: "1600 amphitheatre way "
address_2: "Mountain View, CA 94043"
affiliation_attributes: Array[0]
award_attributes: Array[0]
certification_attributes: Array[0]
description: ""
description_read_more: false
education_attributes: Array[1]
id: 1
lat: "37.422003"
lng: "-122.083978"
name: "Gio Wong"
phone: "650-701-6411"
photos: Array[3]
practice_name: "Super Doctor"
rating: null
rating_url: null
salutation: "DDS"
services: Array[4]
specialty: "Pediatrician"
__proto__: f
```

I'm trying to access education,affiliation, award and certification attributes. The following code is how i print to console and how the promise object is get

```
$scope.provider = Provider.get($routeParams.name);
console.log($scope.provider)
```

how do i access $scope.provider.education_attributes.length? or even $scope.provider.education_attributes[0]? both returned cannot read property.

Comment: Maybe this helps to learn how promises work: http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html

Answer (score 4):

The provider function returns an Angular Promise object.  It does not directly return your data.  Instead you provide the Promise with a function to call once the Promise has resolved.

You should instead do:

```
Provider.get($routeParams.name).then(function(resolveData) {
  //access stuff on resolveData here
});
```

See "The Promise API" section of [Angular's $q service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).